# Using a DLL in the Web API Project

Tags: c#, api, iis

I want to use a dll which communicates with a server, while using the DLL in the Console Application in C# it worked fine. But when I am using the DLLs in the Web API project it is not making any logs and also not returning correct response.

The DLL uses a .config file which should be present in the same location as that of the DLL. I have pasted the config file in the bin folder in both the cases but still got the different results.

what would be the possible reason behind this.

Comment: the DLL also creates logs if working properly

Comment: We could really use more information, like what is the DLL?  Can you show any code from the DLL?  Also, does the config file need to be in the same directory as the DLL or does it need to be in the working directory?

Comment: Is the web api on the same computer as the console application? Is the same user account being used?  What are the differences in configurations where the working and non working apps are running?

Comment: Actually I do not have the code of the DLL. I have observed that .config file should be in the same location because after pasting the .Config file in the bin/Debug folder of the console application it worked as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to share the config file? Also, have you tried putting try catch blocks around the code calling the dll method and log the exception?

Comment: The config file have the basic information e.g server address, maximum number of attempts etc. What I am thinking is that the DLLs are not getting the .Config file.

Comment: The Code is not throwing any exception it is giving me the response. and the response is "not configured"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IIS` uses [Shadow Copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies), i.e. it copies all `DLL`s from `bin` into temporary folder. Your configuration file is probably not copied during this process, causing your communication `DLL` to fail in finding it's `.config`.

You could either copy `.config` file to target temporary bin folder during application startup, or [disable shadow copying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.hostingenvironmentsection.shadowcopybinassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx)  in `web.config` (with all it's [side effects](https://www.ajaymatharu.com/side-effect-of-shadowcopybinassemblies/)).

Comment: Yes, you are right but I have checked the location of both the DLL and the .config file at runtime. both of them are at same location C/Program Files x86/ IISExpress

Comment: The DLL will try to create the logs in run lime at the location where it is present but I can't see any logs in that folder.

Comment: *C/Program Files x86/ IISExpress* is root directory of your WebAPI application? Or is it target forder for shadow copying? Or does your application load DLL manually from this predefined location? Shaddow-copying typically uses directory like *c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\....* - this is where your `DLL` and `.config` and `logs` should be.

Comment: There is no file in the location that mentioned above. I haven't changed anything about the the root directory or the target directory so it would be taking the default setting .

Comment: if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(MyProject.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current_Log\\"))) 
  
  Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(MyProject.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current_Log\\"));

Comment: This is the code written in the DLL for creating the logs

Comment: If `bin` is not shadowed in *Temporary ASP.NET Files* directory, it must be somewhere else. Reliable way to find out is in Visual Studio -> Debug -> Windows -> Modules. At list all DLLs actually loadedd by process. Find your DLL and it's path. If log isn't there and path is not subject to [filesystem virtualization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927387/common-file-and-registry-virtualization-issues-in-windows-vista-or-in), it's possible, that your application doesn't have permission to write to this directory and DLL just silently swallow exception instead of rethrowing it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, now the logs are getting created after setting shadow loading to false. What will be the side effects of stopping shadow loading in an WEB API project.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, plese accept it as a solution. When shadow-copying is disabled, you will be unable to overwrite files in `bin` directory while web server is runnig. So you wil have to stop web server (or application pool) temporarily for each application update.